# How do I find out if I made my Google account correctly?

Tags: google-account, google-my-business

When you sign up for a Google account it asks you whether the account is for yourself or your business and I can't remember what I used. How can I check whether my Google account is for business or not and if it isn't how can I change it to a business account?

Comment: Google business is here: https://www.google.com/business/ Individuals can run businesses. So if your email is as a business or individual it does not mean you can not use it to run a business. I do set up business email accounts but I've set most of them up as individual because business was not an option.